# SQL - Select from 2 tables almost identical tables

Tags: sql, join

I have a set of 2 tables , what I am  trying to achieve is select all from both , and display from which table it was selected + active=1 set from the values taken from table2 (in the first table there is a boolean = active, everything in table2 is active no need for this column there) but as I wrote I still want the data being selected from table2 set as active in result.

I am totally stuck, would really appreciate some help.

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` bool DEFAULT NULL,
)


CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *, 't1' tableName
FROM table1

UNION ALL

SELECT *, true 'active', 't2' tableName
FROM table2
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b3e3/1)**

Comment: Wow! Awesome Marcin lots of <3